# Error with {n,m} wildcard search in MS Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm encountering a very frustrating error where I get the message "The Find What text contains a Pattern Match expression which is not valid." whenever I try to run a search+replace in Word 2010 using the {n,} or {n,m} wildcards - the {n} wildcard works fine, as do all the others. Even using the specific example provided by MS in their Word 2010 support forum ("10{1,3}" to find 10, 100 and 1000) doesn't work (https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-us/article/Find-and-replace-text-by-using-regular-expressions-Advanced-eeaa03b0-e9f3-4921-b1e8-85b0ad1c427f?CorrelationId=9d386d5e-14db-4fc1-87de-b4d2a978ad28&ui=en-US&rs=en-001&ad=US).

Anyone know what the issue could be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regional settings in control panel may have a "List separator" character that is not ",".

I don't believe word *should* work that way, but it does.